# Npm express module not installing

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to install express module of Node JS using command prompt, but getting  error everytime. I have tried the following solutions from similar posts elsewhere, but to no help.
1. Run cmd in administrator mode.
2. Check internet issues. 
The command i am using is

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

I have also tried gd instead of g. 
The error file contents are

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'express-generator' ]
2 info using npm@3.6.0
3 info using node@v5.7.1
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData express-generator
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData express-generator
9 silly mapToRegistry name express-generator
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
13 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
14 verbose request no auth needed
15 info attempt registry request try #1 at 2:21:17 PM
 16 verbose request id b26b9ae72d812cde
17 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
18 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

19 info attempt registry request try #2 at 2:21:27 PM
20 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
21 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

22 info attempt registry request try #3 at 2:22:27 PM
23 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443

24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)

24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at errnoException (dns.js:31:15)
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)

24 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for express-generator { [Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443]
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 443 }
25 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
27 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
29 silly install printInstalled
30 verbose stack Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
30 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
30 verbose stack     at errnoException (dns.js:31:15)
30 verbose stack     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)

31 verbose cwd C:\Users\rachit.gupta09\NodejsApp
32 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
33 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "express-generator"

34 error node v5.7.1
35 error npm  v3.6.0
36 error code EAI_AGAIN
37 error errno EAI_AGAIN
38 error syscall getaddrinfo
39 error getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org:443
40 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
40 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
41 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

The directory where i am running this command contains my js file. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or something? It looks like NPM isn't able to connect to the registry.

Comment: Yes i am using a proxy to access internet. But there are no issues in connectivity.

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11308 . The url mentioned in this post is also accessible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're using a proxy to connect to the internet - NPM by default won't know anything about this, so you'll need to change its global configuration settings.

```
npm config set proxy http://[Host]:[Port]
npm config set https-proxy http://[Host]:[Port]
```

Comment: Joe, the error now is "tunneling socket could not be established. Cause=parse error ".

Comment: Are you definitely using the correct proxy address and port? If you're 100% sure that's not the issue, try `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`, it could be an issue with your proxy not wanting to connect via SSL.

Comment: which port i should be writing in the command?? I am using 443 as it is mentioned in the log file. i have also tried the port i created on the server in create server method of my app. Also i am able to access SSL websites normally on my browser.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what URL you're meant to be setting for the proxy command - it needs to the URL and port **for your proxy server**, not anything to do with your app. Obviously I don't know your setup, so I can't tell you exactly what that is, but ignore the ports in the logs/your code, they're not relevant here.

Comment: Yes Joe, i have used the url and port of my proxy server only. Still no relief

Comment: can you tell from which website npm downloads packages so that i can get exceptional access to it?

Comment: I believe the API is located at https://registry.npmjs.org/ and http://registry.npmjs.org/.